# Create responsive tabs with content from post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am new in Wordpress so I hope I will be very explicit in the following description. Right now I`m trying to create something like https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navs-tabs/ but in Wordpress using bootstrap 5. In the tabs title I want to show the title of the post and in the tab content will be the_content().Thanks in advance !

Comment: All you have to do is use the HTML you linked to with `<?php the_title() ?>` and `<?php the_content() ?>` inserted where you want the title and content to go.

Comment: Thanks for answer but It`s not that easy. I already It and the result are not the best.

Comment: What do you mean by *"the result are not the best"*? You need to describe your problem better than that for us to be able to help you.

Comment: I am sorry if I was not too clear. After I take the html code from bootsrap and write a loop to take the post from the wanted category, I put <?php the_title();?> into the nav pills as the name of the tab and <?php the_content;?> into the tab content but It the result look like this https://prnt.sc/gddzO5YjGYzu ,  not even close to how it is supposed to look like.

Comment: Here is the code, I`ve uploaded It on codepen: https://codepen.io/brbgrg/pen/mdXxVeb

Comment: Thank you. That's helpful. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `ul` needs to be outside of the while loop so that you only have a single navigation component. Right now it is creating a separate navigation for every oracion. Try the following:

```
  <div class="col-md-9">
            <?php
            $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'category_name' => 'orar',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
            )); ?>
            <?php if ($wpb_all_query->have_posts()) : ?>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                <?php while ($wpb_all_query->have_posts()) :
                    $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
                            <button class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="pill" data-bs-target="#pills-profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false"><?php $wpb_all_query->the_title(); ?></button>
                        </li>
                   
                    <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
                        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab"><?php $wpb_all_query->the_content(); ?></div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </ul>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php
            else : ?>
                <p><?php ('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
            <?php
            endif; ?>
   </div>
```

Comment: Still don`t work, it shows me just an empty pill.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for trying to help me. :d